# Puppet - including another file

Tags: templates, puppet, ssh-keys

is there a way to insert one Puppet file into other Puppet files ?

We do have a lot of servers with SSH key definitions managed by Puppet and I would like to have something like a separate file for all the SSH key definitions. The main goal is to update the key definitions only in a few places instead of all our server definitions.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [class](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/lang_classes.html) - it's a container for resources (like your SSH key resources) that you can add to nodes or from other classes with a single line. When you add it, the node gets all of the resources inside.

```
class sshkeys {
  ssh_authorized_key { 'foo@example.com':
    ensure => present,
    user   => 'foo',
    type   => 'ssh-rsa',
    key    => 'AAAAB3Nza[...]qXfdaQ==',
  }

  ssh_authorized_key { 'bar@example.com':
    # more...
  }
}
```

And then in your `node` block, use `include`:

```
node foo.example.com {
  include sshkeys
}
```

The class definition can either be in the same or another file in the manifests directory, or preferably you can start putting them into [a module layout](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/modules_fundamentals.html), i.e. `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/environments/production/sshkeys/manifests/init.pp` where Puppet will automatically load it. Modules help you encapsulate functionality, as you can store files, templates and more specific manifests and classes together.